# Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://sts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" in AWS EKS with IRSA for RDS,S3 and security groups applied for RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-s3, amazon-eks

I created a cluster where a pod should read/write data from/to RDS and S3. In order to make the connection secure, I added IRSA for S3 and RDS. An additional layer of security was added by creating a security group for the pod so that it can talk to RDS. However after doing this, while the pod can write to RDS and S3 without any issues, pod can read only from RDS and not from S3. I exec'd into the pod to see what was happening. When I execute `aws s3 ls` and `aws sts get-caller-identity`. I get `Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://sts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"` as output.

In order to implement security groups for pods, I followed https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/security-groups-for-pods.html. I understand that when security group is applied to a pod, source NAT is disabled so I created a VPC endpoint for S3 (Gateway Endpoint). I created an outbound rule in the pod's security group to access managed prefix list for S3 as well. I followed instructions on [Managing Amazon S3 access with VPC endpoints and S3 Access Points](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/managing-amazon-s3-access-with-vpc-endpoints-and-s3-access-points/) for this. This didn't help with execution of the commands that I showed earlier.

I also created an Interface VPC Endpoint for STS but that didn't work either.

I have referred to https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/issues/1211 as well. I am already following the instructions mentioned in this post as the dns resolution is active for my cluster.